# Edit option of select box using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

There is list.

```
<select id="select_box">
  <option>Select State</option>
  <option value='state1'>State 1<option>
  <option value='state2'>State 2<option>
</select>
```

How can i set value of the text 'Select State' as '-1' i.e. list become

```
<select id="select_box">
  <option value='-1'>Select State</option>
  <option value='state1'>State 1<option>
  <option value='state2'>State 2<option>
</select>
```

I have tried

```
$('#select_box')
    .find('Select State')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="-1">Select State</option>');
```

But, due to above code, it displays at the end of select box. I want to maintain the order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just...

```
$('#select_box')[0].options[0].value = -1;
```

... as you're able to update `value` property of this `<option>` element (and in fact, it's much better than removing previous element, then appending a new one).

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could always use

`$('#select_box option:first').val('-1');`

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$("select_box option:first-child").attr('value', '-1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nm2c9/

Answer (score 0):

Try looping all options and check for the inner text and replace the value

```
$('#select_box option').each(function()
{
    if($(this).text()=="Select State"){
       $(this).val("-1");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to find the requested element:

```
var $option = $('#select_box').find('option:contains("Select State")');
```

After that you can change the value of the element:

```
$option.val('-1');
```